# How to correctly design a Typescript interface whose attributes are set at different times (Angular 2 app)?

Tags: typescript, angular

In my Angular 2 - Typescript application I have an interface.

**someType.ts**

```
export interface SomeType {
    attr1: string;
    attr2: number;
    attr3?: SomeType2
}
```

and a service using SomeType for **type checking**.

**DataService.ts**

```
import {SomeType} from './someType;

export class DataService {
    storedData: SomeType;

    setFirstStepData(<data>){
        // here is where I'm not sure which is the right design choice
        // storedData. ...
    }

    getData(stepNumber: number){
        switch(...) {
           // ...
        }
    }
}
```

At the end I will get the actual object from a service so **all attributes** will be set except for special cases. However **storedData (which holds temporary 'in-memory' data) is initialized in across multiple components.**

Precisely I should work like this:

> firstComponent sets storedData's attr1 and attr2 via a DataService. then route to secondComponent which will store attr3 still via DataService. Finally when all attributes are set, data is sent to the backend

I see two possible options here:

- set someType with **all optional attributes, except for those I know will be set for sure by the first component** using DataService and create . then the various components via DataService would **set individual properties** of storedData without therefore giving type errors. It seems a viable solution but a little bit 'twisted'
- **instead of using storedData** I'd use attr1, attr2 etc. directly in **DataService**. However since SomeType actually matches a model from the backend it doesn't sound a good design choice

Which solution is better on a **design level**? If neither of them is good enough, which is the **right / most appropriate** way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is at the core of this solution.

*Interfaces* are designed to be **implemented** from different classes, not to be modified at runtime. Moreover, Interfaces are erased at runtime. In fact decorators don't support interfaces either.

If you have to set SomeType once only at the creation of your services, you can implement the Interface setting the methods/parameters based on your needs.

But if you need to change SomeType dinamically, Interfaces are not the right choice. In this case you could use a **Factory**, returning your object initialized on your needs.

**EDITED**

Here is a factory example with your code:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeTypeFactory {
    getSomeType(attr1:string, attr2:number, attr3?:SomeType2){
        let someType = {
            attr1,
            attr2,
            attr3
        };
        return someType;
    }
}
```

This is a *Factory Service*. You can inject it in the classes where you want to define your custom someType.

After injecting it and initialing it in the constructor `constructor(private factory:SomeTypeFactory) {}`
you can use it to initialite someType:

```
this.someType = this.factory.getSomeType('a',1, /*Optional SomeType2*/);
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want to use the SomeType model you can insert the class SomeType in the factory:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";

 class SomeType {
    attr1: string;
    attr2: number;
    attr3: any;
    constructor(attr1:string, attr2:number, attr3?:any) {
            this.attr1 = attr1;
            this.attr2 = attr2;
            this.attr3 = attr3;
        }
    }

@Injectable()
export class SomeTypeFactory {
    getSomeType(attr1:string, attr2:number, attr3?:any){
        return new SomeType(attr1,attr2,attr3);
    }
}
```

Hoping this helps ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer. could you please provide a concrete example on how to do it with a Factory? I couldn't find much in the docs

Comment: One question: is the optional attr3 attribute of type _SomeType_ or of type _any_?

Comment: it's a class with several attributes (just like SomeType but with different attributes). I edited the definition to make it clearer

Comment: thanks for the follow up. so, there is no "factory" specialized class? also, I guess the factory should return a different someType based on the current available attributes. however it's not very clear if and how I should use SomeType definition for type checking as the original purpose was to match as much as possible SomeType model in the backend (see SomeType in my original question). can you also clarify this?

Comment: of course after these clarifications I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: Sure! If you want to match your backend model you can define the SomeType class in the SomeTypeFactory model and return a new instance of it in the getSomeType method.  I've inserted a second editing with an example ;)